# Reticulate can't find Anaconda installation

Tags: r, anaconda, reticulate

I have Anaconda installed on my Mac, and there doesn't seem to be any issue with it. However, the `reticulate` package does't find my installation even though it's been added to my `$PATH`.

This is my `$PATH`:

`/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`

But whenever I run

```
library(reticulate)
conda_list()
```

I get the following error: `Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?`

Why isn't `reticulate` finding Anaconda even when it's on `$PATH`?